# Is there a difference in browser performance when using Javascript to create elements or plain text

Tags: javascript, performance

My research didn't prove very succsessful since I don't really know how to explain it when it is not by example.

Consider the following:

You have a webpage. One div of the webpage will by dynamic, meaning that it will load different things, like tables, paragraphs, ect ect.

Let's have set the div's id to 'main' and have this for conveneance:

```
var main = document.getElementById("main");
```

Now, this is the tricky part: When you want to change it's children you have 2 options:

1) Remove all children; create a variable in javascript for each new element; style it; set inner html; append.
Example:

```
//Consider that the children have already be cleared
     var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = "Hello World";
        p.className = "style";
        main.appendChild(p);

    var p2 = document.createElement("p");
    p2.innerHTML = "Goodbye world!";
    p2.className = "byeStyle";
    main.appendChild(p);
```

2) Set the inner html of the variable to, basically what you want it to be.
Example2:

```
 main.innerHTML = '<p class="style">Hello world!</p>' +
                    '<p class="byeStyle">Goodbye world!</p>';
```

Both will work fine. Which is preferred and which has better performance?

Comment: strictly speaking for a fair comparison your first block should be using `document.createTextNode` to make the elements' contents.

Comment: Assigning to `innerHTML` is usually much faster. Browsers have optimized HTML parsers, since that's what they do 99% of the time.

Comment: If you want to see the difference, make a benchmark at jsperf.com.

Comment: @Barmar I've seen JS perf benchmarks that suggest there's little difference on modern browsers.

Comment: The fact is, unless you're doing it hundreds of times in a tight loop, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Alnitak It really depends on how much you're doing. If you build an entire complex page using DOM update methods, it will be significantly slower.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, that's what I just said.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. I wish both you cloud make an answer so I can at least +1 you.

Comment: look at http://jsperf.com/node-creation-html-vs-dom

Comment: Higher is better, so the html way has a significant difference in Chrome. Interesting. Thank you for making this post!

Comment: @ArunPJohny your jsperf was broken and produced bad results - `main` was undefined in the second test.  See http://jsperf.com/node-creation-html-vs-dom/2

Comment: Interesting. So it turns out that the HTML approach is actually slower ? I honestly didn't expect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it doesn't matter unless you're doing this over and over in a tight loop.

Perceived wisdom is that using `.innerHTML` is faster, however on modern browsers that is not necessarily the case.

See e.g. http://jsperf.com/node-creation-html-vs-dom/2, where using raw DOM access on Chrome version 28 is 5x faster than using `.innerHTML`.

Comment: So, when the change is made only when, for example pressing a button, the difference is irrelevant ?

Comment: @Bloodcount pretty much, yes, unless you're going to be updating hundreds of nodes.  If it's just a couple of nodes, just go for cleanest code.